# How do I preserve credentials for Tomcat service when update(reinstall) Tomcat from 32bit to 64bit on Windows?

Tags: windows, service, tomcat8

I have 32 bit installer that install tomcat 8 as a service on windows 7/10.

I changed the tomcat version to be 64 bit and when I try to update the app with the new tomcat my tomcat service credentials are resetting. 
Which is expected since I am removing the service and create it again.

Is there a solution for the tomcat service creds to be preserved after I install the new tomcat?

Is there a way to do tomcat service update? (I am using NSIS)

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Failed installing 'myservice' service

SERVICE_NAME: myservice 
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
updating the description for the myservice service
```

[image]